# Javascript keeps track of functions data

Tags: javascript

I created this function:

```
window.showModal = function(args){
    var defaults = {
        type: 'success',
        title: 'Informazioni',
        info: 'Testo di informazioni',
        cancel: 'Annulla',
        nocancel: false,
        confirm: 'Ok',
        action: false,
        isAjax: false,
        goTo: false,
    }

    args = args || defaults;
    for (var opt in defaults) {
        if (defaults.hasOwnProperty(opt) && !args.hasOwnProperty(opt)) {
            args[opt] = defaults[opt];
        }
    }

    alert(args['action'])

    $('#modal_generic_cancel').show();

    $('#modal_generic_title').addClass('uk-text-'+args['type']).html(args['title']);
    $('#modal_generic_info').html(args['info']);
    $('#modal_generic_cancel').html(args['cancel']);
    $('#modal_generic_confirm').html(args['confirm']);

    if(args['nocancel']){
        $('#modal_generic_cancel').hide();
    }

    if(args['action'] == false){
        $('#modal_generic_confirm').addClass('uk-modal-close');
        $('#modal_generic_cancel').hide();
    }

    if(args['action'] && !args['isAjax']){
        $('#modal_generic_confirm').click(function(){
            window.location = base_url()+args['goTo'];
        });
    }
    if(args['action'] && args['isAjax']){
        $('#modal_generic_confirm').click(function(){
            alert(args['action'])
        });
    }

    UIkit.modal("#modal_generic").show();
}
```

For some reason when I call this function:

```
showModal({type:'danger', title:'Errore', info: "Funzione modifica cliente non ancora implementata."});
```

The "action" is not defined, therefore is `false`. If I click on the next button:

```
showModal({type:'danger', title:'Eliminare il cliente?', info:'Siete sicuri di voler eliminare il cliente selezionato?', cancel:'No', confirm:'Si, elimina', action:'tables/deleteCustomer/'+customer_id, isAjax:true, goTo:'main/show/'+customer_id})
```

Than click back to the first one, `action` is set to:

```
tables/deleteCustomer/38
```

Instead of taking the `default{}` value (false) it keeps the one of the other button.

Here a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mrweb/x3fLq6o5/1/

Comment: You should declare new variables with `var`. `defaults` is a global variable in this code. Do you have any other functions which declare a `defaults` variable?

Comment: Ok I put var prior to the default var declaration. Yes I have other functions with default car declared. Does it matter? I thought inside the function you can re-use same names. Am I wrong?

Comment: It only matters that you didn't place `var` in front of them. That means you only have one global `defaults` variable that you're setting in each function. Placing `var` in front of it makes sure that the variable is only declared for that function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `defaults` object is global. To prevent creating global objects (plus other advantages) pay attention to the **["use strict"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)** mode.

As I see you are using **jQuery** then I promote the cloning objects technique by using the **[jQuery.extend()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)** method.

Also I promote the use of **[IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)** to create isolated scopes, where you can specify the context in which your methods are linked.

Learn more about **[MODULE PATTERN](https://toddmotto.com/mastering-the-module-pattern/)**

```
//begin IIFE
(function (context) {

    "use strict";

    var defaults = {
        type: 'success',
        title: 'Informazioni',
        info: 'Testo di informazioni',
        cancel: 'Annulla',
        nocancel: false,
        confirm: 'Ok',
        action: false,
        isAjax: false,
        goTo: false
    };

    context.showModal = function (args) {
        //Merge the contents of two or more objects together into the first object;
        //that is, defaults and args into the options
        var options = $.extend({}, defaults, args);

        //TODO: use options as the new options passed to the function
        //e.g. options.isAjax; options.goTo, ...
    };

}(window));
//window is imported as the context object;
//you can switch the window object to your own namespace object.

//usage
window.showModal({/* options */});
```

Also take into account that every time you invoke the `showModal` method you are ***rebinding*** new handlers to the `click` event. To prevent that, you can detach existing event handlers by calling the **[.off()](https://api.jquery.com/off/)** method, e.g.

```
$('#modal_generic_confirm').off("click.myns").on("click.myns", eventHandler);
```

Comment: Tks a lot. The issue was with the `off()`.